# put width of 100% to a div that is inside a <body> tag that have a max-width: 1200px

Tags: html, css

I have a body class with `max-with: 1200px`.

I have this because I want that my biggest divs with class `.row` have this max width.

But I want that my divs with class `.fullrow` have 100% width (but not 100% of 1200px).

Do you see a good way to fix this?  I was thinking about putting this `"max-width: 1200px;`" outside `<body>` but then im not seeing a good way for doing this..

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bLcyvfd6/3/

HTML:

```
 <body>
    <div class="fullrow">
        fullrow
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
           col
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
           col
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body{
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 320px;
        max-width: 1200px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .fullrow{
        width: 100%;
        margin:0 auto;
        background: green;
    }

    .row{
        padding: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
        float:left;
        background:yellow;
    }

    .col{
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
```

Comment: It seems to work for me. `.fullrow` is as wide as `body`, whether it's `1200px` or less.

Comment: i think this might be what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/bLcyvfd6/4/

Comment: Why not set the max-width on .col?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that I can see would be to remove your `max-width` property on the `body` element, and add it to your `.row` element.

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.fullrow{
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: green;
}

.row{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
    max-width: 1200px;
}

.col{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bLcyvfd6/6/

Comment: You have to hit "Update" and then "Share" on JSFiddle to get a new URL. That's the OP's URL.

Comment: @Dan you're totally right... thanks! I've edited my answer to include the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the padding from the `.row` `max-width` property.

```
.row
{
   /*other styles*/
   padding:20px;
   max-width: 1160px;/*1200 - (20*2)*/
}
```

Link to an update of example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bLcyvfd6/5/)

Edit:

If you don't want to restrict `.fullrow` width then remove `max-width` from the body tag like this.

```
body
{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```